# Browserify-shim not reading a transform from the package.json

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I am trying to use `browserify` to build a new project that my team is working on, but it does not recognize the transform from the `package.json`.  It will build on 2 machines, but on 2 others it will not build.

Here is the relevant piece of my `package.json`.

```
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "angular": "./src/main/webapp/js/lib/angular.js",
    "angular-route": "./src/main/webapp/js/lib/angular-route.js",
    "underscore": "./src/main/webapp/js/lib/lodash.compat.js",
    "restangular": "./src/main/webapp/js/lib/restangular.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular": {},
    "angular-route": {
      "depends": [
        "angular"
      ]
    },
    "underscore": {
      "exports": "_"
    },
    "restangular": {
      "depends": [
        "underscore",
        "angular"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am running browserify from the command line.  I have 4 computers on my team and it is working on a `Mac` and a `Windows` machine, but I have 2 `Windows` machine that it does not work on.  We have all pulled from the same repo, all of our `browserify` and `npm` versions are the same.  What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

The `Windows` machines were running the command from `git bash`.  The command would not work with on `git bash`.  After we switched to the `command prompt`, then all of the commands run fine.

Comment: yeah nodejs on windows makes a lot of assumptions about the environment only checking for %ENV_TYPE_VARS%. Which sadly means for npm and bower, you can't use the superior bash shell in the superior Cmder terminal on windows.